# Exclude hoe gem dependency from Heroku

Tags: heroku, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to push code to Heroku and it seems like the system gem "hoe" is somehow included by some other gem (geokit was one of them but no luck even after removing that gem from Gemfile). This is causing Heroku to fail because it cannot update system gems. how to solve this issue?

```
Installing geokit (1.5.0) 
   Installing geonames (0.2.2) 
   Installing hoe (2.9.1) /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in `install': hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
```

!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

Answer (score 6):

Just pin it in your Gemfile, I bet your dependent gems don't depend on 2.9.1. Add this:

```
gem 'hoe', '~> 1.5.1' # Heroku's rubygems is too old for hoe 2.9.1 as of 28 Mar 2011
```